# How to read xml siblings using XmlReader in C#

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I want to read two elements which are siblings, please suggest me appropriate way to do it using XmlReader in C#

Here is my XML

```
    <loginReturn>
        <canumber>100556369</canumber>
        <emailid>bhushan.patil@servpro.in</emailid>
        <firstname>abc</firstname>
        <lastname>abc</lastname>
        <masterca/>
        <message>Login succesful !</message>
        <meternumber>8683169</meternumber>
        <mobilenumber>1111111111</mobilenumber>
        <status>1</status>
        <subca/>
        <username>abcbbb</username>
     </loginReturn>
```

I want to read "Status" first and if its not equal to "1" then read "message"...

Here is my code:

```
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            string msg = Strings.SUCCESS;

            reader.ReadToFollowing("status");
            var x = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();

            if (x != 1)
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("message");
                msg = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }

            return msg;
        }
```

Comment: I think it's better to read it all at first and on the next step to do some logic work and process your data.

Comment: Do not assume ordering (even if it _seems_ fixed). Just read both _message_ and _status_ (using ReadToNextSibling() to skip what you don't need) and when you have them then perform your logic (yes it'll subtly hit performance but unless you have to process 10M nodes IMO you won't notice any difference).

Comment: with 'reader.ReadToFollowing("status")' cursor moves to "status" node.. after that  **reader** only points inside "status" element.. how can i read both elements and store in var.. please suggest with code

Comment: If my answer could help you to solve your problem, it would be very kind of you to vote it up and mark it as accepted, thx!

Comment: This seems still to be an open problem... Do you need further help?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Your comment made clear, that XmlDocument is not available in Xamarin. I have no experienc with Xamarin and no chance to test it. But a short research brought me to `XPathDocument` (to create an `XPathNavigator`) which seems to be supported in Xamarin. The solution could be something like this:

```
    string msg="OK";
    if(YourNavigator.Evaluate("/loginReturn/status/text()")!="1")
        msg=YourNavigator.Evaluate("loginReturn/message/text()");
```

This is completely untested "air-code"...Hope this helps...

Here's my former answer with XmlDocument - regrettfully not working in Xamarin:

```
    string xml="<loginReturn><canumber>100556369</canumber><emailid>bhushan.patil@servpro.in</emailid>" +
               "<firstname>abc</firstname><lastname>abc</lastname><masterca/><message>Login succesful !</message>" + 
               "<meternumber>8683169</meternumber><mobilenumber>1111111111</mobilenumber><status>1</status><subca/>" + 
               "<username>abcbbb</username></loginReturn>";
    XmlDocument xdoc= new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

    string msg="OK";
    if(xdoc["loginReturn"]["status"].InnerText!="1")
        msg=xdoc["loginReturn"]["message"].InnerText;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but i cannot use XmlDocument.... i am coding in Xamarin PCL which does not support XmlDocument